# Assistance With KeyEvent

Tags: java, swing, key, coordinates, keyevent

I am making a platformer game for a class project and so far all I have been able to do is add the chicken character to the game. I need to be able to have him move forward on the press of "D" or right arrow. My code is:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main(){

        //Creates Title Image 
        JLabel title = new JLabel(" ");
        ImageIcon tl = new ImageIcon("title.gif");
        title.setIcon(tl);

        //Creates Start Image
        final JButton start = new JButton("");
        ImageIcon st = new ImageIcon("start.gif");
        start.setIcon(st);

        //Creates Options Image
        JButton options = new JButton("");
        ImageIcon opt = new ImageIcon("options.gif");
        options.setIcon(opt);
        options.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //Create first frame for "Start" button
        final JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        p1.add(start, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Create second panel for title label
        final JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        p2.add(title, BorderLayout.WEST);

        //Create third panel for "Options" button
        final JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        p3.add(options, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Creates fourth panel to organize all other primary
        final JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        p4.add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        p4.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p4.add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);


        //When button is clicked, it changes the level
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(start.isEnabled()) {
                    remove(p4);
                    setSize(1440, 500);
                    add(new ContentPanel1());
                    validate();
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        //Adds fourth panel to frame
        add(p4, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Main frame = new Main();

        //Finds screen size of monitor
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        //Creates the frame
        frame.setTitle("Cockadoodle Duty: Awakening");
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setLocale(null); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        String background = "#000000";
        frame.setBackground(Color.decode(background));
    }
}

class coordinate {
    public static int x;
    public static int y;
}

class ContentPanel1 extends JPanel{
    Image back = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("level0.gif");
    Image chick = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("chicken.gif");

    ContentPanel1() {
        MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);

        mt.addImage(back, 0);
        try {
            mt.waitForAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        coordinate.x = 20;
        coordinate.y = 321;

        super.paintComponent(g);
        int imwidth = back.getWidth(null);
        int imheight = back.getHeight(null);
        g.drawImage(back, 1, 1, null);
        g.drawImage(chick, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, null);
    }

    public void MoveDirection(KeyEvent e, Graphics g) {
          coordinate.x = 20;
          coordinate.y = 321;

          super.paintComponent(g);
          int key = e.getKeyCode();

          if(key == 68) {
              coordinate.x += 1;
              g.drawImage(chick, coordinate.x, coordinate.y, null);
          }
      } 
}
```

The main trouble I have been having with my code is the bit at the end with the `MoveDirection` method. The way I have it going is by adding a new chicken to the frame (This was mainly due to the fact that I was just testing to see if the code worked). Is there a better way to do that too?

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

- NEVER call `super.paintComponent(g);` (or `paintComponent(g);`) directly from outside the context of the `paintComponent` method, there is a lot more to painting then just painting the component background. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.  Instead, simply call `repaint` when you want to, well, repaint the component.
- The use of `MediaTracker` is out of date and you should be using the `ImageIO` API instead, which will block automatically while reading the image.  See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details
- Don't use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` in combination with `JFrame#setSize`, the `getScreenSize` method does not take into account things like the task bar or dock of some OS's, instead use the `JFrame#setExtendedState` and pass it `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`
- `frame.setLocale(null);` isn't doing what you think it is